# Google Play: Your device is incompatible with this version -> "No Carrier"

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I can't find anything online for this. 
A user mentioned that he couldn't download my App because Google Play wouldn't let him. So I bought the device the user has (Galaxy Tab 3) because I couldn't figure it out remotely.

I can't find the App in the Play Store on the device. If I log in with the same Google account, it tells me that my device is incompatible with this App. All the information I have is "No Carrier".

Could it be possible that if my App needs an Internet connection I can't download the App if the device doesn't have a Sim-Card or something?

**Update:**
I have another flavor of this app in the store. The only difference (manifest-wise) is that this app needs camera permissions. But even if I make those optional (setting 'required' to false), it doesn't help. Also the specific model 'GT-P5210' is not listed in neither of my Apps in the supported devices list (even though I can find the other app in the store with the device). Also I made sure that there are screenshots for every possible tablet size.
Also I can of course install the App from Android Studio.

Comment: could be a lot of things. permissions, screen size, feature... Inspecting your manifest would help. I would try removing stuff from the manifest until my device is in the supported list in the console.

Answer (score 1):

in the google play console, under store listing

add some screenshots for "TABLET".

without that, google play will think that your app is not meant for Tablets (which Galaxy Tab 3 is classified under).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but sadly it didn't help. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is a requirement listed in the app's manifest for phone networking. You need a phone to use it.